# What does mean 'protruding 'in this sentence?

Tags: expressions

Mrs.Taylor, a kind lady with gray Elsa Lanchester-Bride of
Frankenstein hair and *protruding* eyes.

[On writing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439156816)

Answer (score 1):

Take in the literal sense:

[protruding](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/protruding):

> sticking out, bulging

She had large, bulging eyes (think Homer Simpson), and judging by the hair she may have been kind but probably looked a bit scary.